# Creating/Simulating a dataset from total data

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, csv

I am doing work on census data and wanted to make my own data set from the totals that has been collated into individual data-points/instances. Say 1000 people were surveyed, I have put an example of what I would like to go from and then would like go to. Currently I have this data as excel file.

Is there a Python package I can use or should I use Pandas?

from this:

| Male | Female | Car | Bike | Walk | Married | Not Married |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 500 | 500 | 200 | 200 | 600 | 450 | 550 |

to this:

| Person | Gender | Transport | Marriage_Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Male | Car | Married |
| 2 | Female | Walk | Not_married |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 999 | Female | Bike | Not_married |
| 1000 | Female | Walk | Not_married |

I haven't really tried anything yet as I am not sure where to start with this sort of challenge.

Comment: Do you have any notion on how these data are distributed in connection with each other? I mean, hardly the purpose is to shuffle the lists like `Transport = ['Car']*200 + ['Bike']*200 + ['Walk']*600; random.shuffle(Transport)`. You have to know some joined variability between these parameters before mocking the data, right?

Comment: Technically, you can create 1000 data points but only at the expense of making all sorts of assumptions. Unless you have additional information beyond the census results you are using such assumptions are meaningless and, unfortunately, you risk fooling yourself that by creating 1000 data points you have somehow added more information. You haven't, you have just added a load of unjustified and unstated assumptions to the limited information you actually have.

Comment: @Vitalizzare how would I introduce these variabilites? So my actual dataset haas a population of 310306.

Gender: Male = 155869, Female =154437
Disability: Disabled = 40125, Not Disabled = 270181
General Health: Very Good = 164359, Good = 99697, Fair = 31182, Bad = 11172, Very Bad = 3896
For these three, I can just use the code similar to what miloserdow put. If I want to introduce another category that does not have the same total as the population, how would I do that, for example number of people in a household?

Comment: @DMM could please read my comment to Vitalizarre and add any thoughts. I guess these were the assumptions and variability you were both were talking about.

Comment: The best advice I can give is to learn something about statistics and probability and specifically about joint probability distributions and independence. Doing this will give you clear insight into the type of assumptions you are making in manufacturing your data set and whether these can be justified or not. I hope that this question is not part of something more serious, such  as using your manufactured data to guide decision making. If it is, the decisions will not be particularly good and might even be disastrously bad.

Comment: @DMM Thank you for the advice, I needed that. I do understand joint probability distributions and independence, I think I just kept trying to go on with blinders on and trying to force this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Before solving this problem, let's set out some assumptions:

- The categories (`Male` and `Female`, `Car` and `Bike`, etc.) don't overlap. For example, if `Car' is 200, it means there are 200 unique people who prefer the car as their transport.
- The sum in each resulting category (e.g. `Transport`, `Gender`, etc) is equal to the total number of the population.
- Data is complete and well-formatted.

Now, we can use *Pandas* for data manipulation to solve this problem.

```
    import pandas as pd
    
    # Read your data
    df = pd.read_excel('your_file.xlsx')
    
    # Create 'Gender' column
    male = ['Male'] * df.loc[0, 'Male']
    female = ['Female'] * df.loc[0, 'Female']
    gender = male + female
    
    # Create 'Transport' column
    car = ['Car'] * df.loc[0, 'Car']
    bike = ['Bike'] * df.loc[0, 'Bike']
    walk = ['Walk'] * df.loc[0, 'Walk']
    transport = car + bike + walk
    
    # Create 'Marriage_Status' column
    married = ['Married'] * df.loc[0, 'Married']
    not_married = ['Not_married'] * df.loc[0, 'Not Married']
    marriage_status = married + not_married
    
    # Create 'Person' column
    person = list(range(1, df.loc[0, 'Male'] + df.loc[0, 'Female'] + 1))
    
    # Create the new DataFrame
    new_df = pd.DataFrame({'Person': person, 'Gender': gender, 'Transport': transport, 'Marriage_Status': marriage_status})
    
    # Save the new DataFrame to an Excel file
    new_df.to_excel('new_file.xlsx', index=False)
```

The solution first reads your data from an Excel file. It then generates lists representing individual data points using the counts from the original dataset. For example, if there are 500 males, it creates a list with 500 'Male' entries. It then similarly compiles the `Transport` and 'Marriage_Status' lists. Then a new data frame is built where each row is a unique person with their attributes. Finally, this data frame is saved to a new Excel file.

Comment: If, as I suspect, the Person column lists 500 Males followed by 500 Females (using OP data) and the Transport column lists 200 Car followed by 800 non-Car, then doesn't this lead to the two columns jointly showing 200 Males and Car, 300 Males and non-Car and 500 Females and non-Car and, by implication, 0 Females and Car?